# How to launch PyCharm from WSL terminal?

Tags: python, linux, windows, pycharm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there a way to run Pycharm from wsl terminal by typing the command like `charm <file_name>` or `pycharm <file_name>`, just like it is with vscode where you type `code <file_name>` ?

Comment: Add the PyCharm exe to your path. It's usually something like `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm installation folder\bin\pycharm64.exe`. However, WSL can't execute windows commands/exes so this only works from windows cmd.

Comment: I assume you mean the *Windows* version of PyCharm?  Or do you mean the Linux version?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It's possible, if you using Windows 11:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps

Comment: That's interesting. Have you actually tried to run PyCharm?

Comment: No, because I'm not using Windows. But some colleagues showed me, when the tried to convince me to change to Windows.

Comment: @ellockie I have tried, works very nicely. Download from https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/?section=linux and follow instructions in "Install-Linux-tar.txt".

Answer (score 2):

From this [article on How to run Windows 10 programs in a WSL Linux shell](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/how-to-run-windows-10-programs-in-a-wsl-linux-shell/), you can already run Windows programs from WSL ex. `notepad.exe`. This is because the program in the WSL path seems to be in sync with Window's path. You can add the path to the PyCharm executable to the path variable, `C:\Users\trakw\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-P\ch-0\221.5921.27\bin`, restart WSL and run `pycharm64.exe` which start PyCharm.

If you're using JetBrains Toolbox to install PyCharm, `C:\Users\trakw\jetbrains\bin`, containing the batch file `pycharm.cmd` to run PyCharm, is already in the path variable.

Running `pycharm.cmd` in WSL will give errors because the .cmd file is written in batch which WSL doesn't recognize.
You need to run it using `cmd.exe /c pycharm`.

You can add [the modified code below](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4547#issuecomment-539824601) to ~/.bashrc file in WSL, so you can run `cmd pycharm .`.

```
# Usage : cmd pycharm .
cmd() {
  CMD=$1
  OPEN=$2
  WIN_PWD=`wslpath -w "$(pwd)"`
  WIN_OPEN=`wslpath -w ${OPEN}`
  pushd /mnt/c;
  cmd.exe /c "${CMD} ${WIN_OPEN}"
  popd;
}

# Disable pushd echoing
pushd () {
    command pushd "$@" > /dev/null
}

# Disable popd echoing
popd () {
    command popd "$@" > /dev/null
}
```

There is still problem. This `cmd pycharm .` in WSL works with projects in `\\wsl$` created in PyCharm. For non-project folder in `\\wsl$`, the error below will show up. However, `pycharm .` in cmd, works with any directory.

[image]

Comment: The path to `pycharm.cmd` is now `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\scripts`, at least for me.

Comment: Too confusing for me.  I just typed `'/c/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.2/bin/pycharm64.exe' .` and magic happened.